# I am trying to organize my ebooks

Tags: windows, organizer-software

I have collected a vast array of ebooks which I would like to sort according to authors. However some authors are

```
 {last name} {first name}
```

And the same author may have books where they are listed

```
  {first name} {last name}
```

I would like to find all of the books by the same author and put them in that author's folder - which will be created using `{first name} {last name}`.

I would like to be able to do something similar for music artist, that is finding all of the similar songs by an artist and creating a folder of that person's name and placing all of the songs by that artist into his/her folder.

Answer (score 4):

I have found no better ebook manager than [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).

Calibre is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books. It has a cornucopia of features divided into the following main categories:

- Library Management
- E-book conversion
- Syncing to e-book reader devices
- Downloading news from the web and converting it into e-book form
- Comprehensive e-book viewer
- Content server for online access to your book collection

Calibre will create a folder system based on author's names.  As for your specific problem with author's names, Calibre can automatically fix most of those errors for you, by matching your book to online sources on the internet.  And even if it doesnt, it makes it really easy to fix them yourself.

I ***highly*** recommend you give it a shot.  This is one of the few free and open source applications that exceed anything in the commercial market.

---

I like to keep my Calibre library in DropBox.  That way I have access to my entire library from any of my computers (Win,Linux, and Mac), as well as the web.

Comment: Thanks but I already have Calibre but it still lists each author no matter whether the first name is first or last. I want to eliminate the number of books if possible.

Comment: inside of Calibre, you can edit the books metadata in bulk, or individually.  To vsm mstvh the first/last name to meet whatever your requirement is.

Comment: @Alexander Calibre can fetch ebook metadata from various sources.. Give this feature a try.

Answer (score 0):

[BookFusion](https://www.bookfusion.com/reading) allows you to organize, sync and read your eBooks across all devices.

- Integrated eBook Reader for Android, iOS and Web
- Sync not only books but your reading progress, bookmarks and comments across all devices
- Organize eBooks by Category, Tags and Authors
- Also integrated with Calibre via their [plugin](https://www.bookfusion.com/reading/calibre)